# Why does AJAX randomly take forever?

Tags: ajax

Sometimes, perhaps once every few hundred AJAX requests and/or where AJAX requests are executing in quick succession, I've seen a request hang for up to several minutes before it completes.  The weird thing is that the request completes successfully AND neither my machine or the server are really doing anything either (e.g. CPU and other resources are not spiking during the "hang").

I've noticed this issue with various web services too, so it isn't just my own website.  It also isn't database related as it has happened on non-database sites.  It also only seems to show up in non-localhost environments.

When I personally use AJAX, I am also using jQuery, so this might also be a jQuery issue.  I also mostly use Firefox, so I don't know if this is just a Firefox issue or if it is an issue any browser could have.  I've run into the issue on multiple computers in multiple locations.

If you have run into this issue before and "fixed" it, I would appreciate the solution you came up with.

Comment: It could be a hangup during the transport at a router...you could try testing it with a traceroute

Answer (score -1):

Use a HTTP debugger like Firebug or Fiddler to track the AJAX requests to see how much time it takes (possible timeout issue due to server setting?) & what HTTP response status code it returns when it fails. Use the [HTTP response status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I've used Firebug.  All requests return HTTP 200 OK.  All the AJAX requests are small requests with theoretically no turnaround time for the response - on my systems, neither endpoint are under load during the "hang".  I forgot to point out that I've been observing this behavior for months.  It seems fairly universal.  It doesn't seem to matter what web server, browser, computer, or network is used.  Let me see if I can replicate the issue more consistently.